# Setting time using html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have html date picker and time picker on my razor page

Like this

[image]

The date populates fine, however there is some issue displaying the time

Here is the view code

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attempt1.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date", @class = "form-control" })
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attempt1.Time, "HH:mm", new { type = "time", @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
```

Only the hour, min, and AM/PM is required

[image]

In browser console, I have a warning but it doesnt state anything from AM/PM.

Has anyone faced this kind of error before? If so, please suggest the change I need to do in razor page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind data with `type="time"`.Here are two solutions:

1.set `Time` to `TimeSpan` type:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attempt1.Time, "HH:mm", new { type = "time", @class = "form-control" })
```

Result(default value of Time:`Time=new TimeSpan(12, 11, 0)`):

[image]

2.set `Time` to string and use  rather than `@Html.TextBoxFor`:

```
public string Time { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<input class="form-control" id="Time" name="Time" type="time" value=@Model.Attempt1.Time>
```

result(default value of Time:`Time="12:11"`):

[image]